# How to make a click on the button change its color in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am making a small game where in I have 50 buttons and when I click on any one of the button, its color changes and amongst them, I have one button which is blue in color. If the player clicks on that blue button, he is a winner. He will be given only three chances.  I have used a button `eventhandler` that takes the color id and accordingly changes the color. But the colorId from the count is 51 and not amongst the 1 - 50 buttons. What is wrong?

```
<html>

 <head>
   <title>Blue-Box</title>
</head>

 <body>
  <script>
    var colorId;
    var button;
    var noOfTries = 3;
    function createButtons() {
        colorId = 0;

        for (var index = 0; index <= 50; index++) {
            button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "box " + index;
            button.id = colorId;
            button.setAttribute("value", colorId);
            button.setAttribute("text", colorId);
            button.style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman";
            button.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0";
            button.style.fontSize = "15px";
            document.body.appendChild(button);
            colorId++;

            button.addEventListener("click", selectColor);

        }

    }

    function selectColor() {
        console.log((colorId));
        console.log("button click");
        if (noOfTries > 0) {
            noOfTries = noOfTries - 1;
            if ((colorId) <= 24) {
                console.log("red color")
                document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor = "#BC8F8F";
            }
            else if (colorId == 25) {
                console.log("blue color")
                document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor = "#0099CC";
                document.write("You Won the game");
                noOfTries = 3;
            }
            else if (colorId > 25 && colorId < 51) {

                document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor = "#008080";

            }
        }
        else {
            document.write("Your attempts have finished");
        }

    }



  </script>

<div id="divbox">
    <button id="buttonbox" onclick="createButtons()">Click to start the Game</button>
</div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: For changing color use `backgroundColor` instead of `color` `document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor="#BC8F8F";`

Comment: The onclick handler should also go inside the loop, else you're only setting an onclick handler for one ID instead of all 50. (And a non-existent ID at that.)

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps you.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Blue-Box</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var colorId = 1;
    var button;
    var lives = 0;
    function createButtons(){

        colorId=0;

        for(var index=1;index<=50;index++){
            button=document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML="box "+index;
            button.id=colorId;
            button.setAttribute("value",colorId);
            button.setAttribute("text",colorId);
            button.style.fontFamily="Times New Roman";
            button.style.backgroundColor="#C0C0C0";
            button.style.fontSize="15px";
            button.addEventListener("click", function(){
                selectColor(this.id);
            })
            document.getElementById("btnbox").appendChild(button);
            colorId++;
        }
    }

    function selectColor(colorId){
        lives++;
        if(lives < 4){
            if (colorId<=24){
                document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor="#BC8F8F";
            }
            else if (colorId==25){
                document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor="#0099CC";
                alert("Winner");
                location.reload();
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor="limegreen";
            }
        }
        else if(lives == 4){
            alert("Game over!");
            location.reload();
        }

    }

</script>
<div id="divbox">
    <button  id="buttonbox" onclick="createButtons()">Click to start the Game</button>
</div>
<div id="btnbox">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// first add a global variable
var noOfTries = 3;

function selectColor() {
  // check if greater than 3
  if(noOfTries > 0) {

    // if yes, then decrement
    noOfTries = noOfTries - 1;

    // continue with the color change
    if (colorId<=24) {
      document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor="#BC8F8F";
    }
    else if (colorId==25) {
      document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor="#0099CC";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById(colorId).style.backgroundColor="limegreen";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
button.addEventListner("click",function() {
  button.style.backgroundColor=nextColor;
})
```

Comment: where to add it

Comment: Also, why to add it.

Comment: And can i use just this -button.addEventListener("click",selectColor());  inside createButtons() function